# Azure Logic Apps form a new array from two array collections based on a condition

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I have two array collections as below

```
"**entitiy1**": [
{
  "lotNumber": "Lot04",
  "itemId": "1000123",
  "locationId": "65668"
},
{
  "lotNumber": "Lot02",
  "itemId": "1000123"
  "locationId": "1000006"
}]


"**entitiy2**":[
{
"storageLocationId": "1000006",
"storageLocationName": "Back Cooler"
},
{
"storageLocationId": "1000007",
"storageLocationName": "Stock Room"
}]
```

The final new array should be formed by matching the data using locationId  and storageLocationId

```
[{
  "lotNumber": "Lot02",
  "itemId": "1000123"
  "locationId": "1000006",
  "storageLocationName":"Back Cooler"
}]
```

I am trying as below. I am looping through one array and filtering the second array with current item matching condition.
**But For each loop always showing as failed. It is showing as previous and next iteration links. When we scroll to the next iteration then it showing as passed for the matching item. But I need only the matching output**

[image]

The 3rd row has matching record
[image]

**How can form a final array with all the matching records?**

```
"For_each": {
            "actions": {
                "Append_to_array_variable": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "name": "finalArray",
                        "value": "@outputs('Compose')"
                    },
                    "runAfter": {
                        "Compose": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                },
                "Compose": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "itemCount": "@items('For_each')?['itemCount']",
                        "locationId": "@items('For_each')?['locationId']",
                        "locationName": "@body('Filter_array')?[0]['storageLocationName']",
                        "lotNumber": "@items('For_each')?['lotNumber']",
                        "sellByDate": "@items('For_each')?['sellByDate']"
                    },
                    "runAfter": {
                        "Filter_array": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": "Compose"
                },
                "Filter_array": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "from": "@body('Select_ESO_Locations')",
                        "where": "@equals(string(item()['storageLocationId']), string(items('For_each')['locationId']))"
                    },
                    "runAfter": {},
                    "type": "Query"
                }
            },
            "foreach": "@body('Select_LSO_Locations')",
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_variable": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Foreach"
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compose action fails because you are trying to read from the filtered array using a hardcoded index [0]. Just change the way you are reading the value to 
Inside for each in Compose
 instead of

```html
"locationName": "@body('Filter_array')?[0]['storageLocationName']",
```

do

```html
"locationName": "@body('Filter_array')?[0]?['storageLocationName']",
```

Your modified For Each should look like following

```html
"For_each": {
            "actions": {
                "Append_to_array_variable": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "name": "finalArray",
                        "value": "@outputs('Compose')"
                    },
                    "runAfter": {
                        "Compose": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                },
                "Compose": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "itemCount": "@items('For_each')?['itemCount']",
                        "locationId": "@items('For_each')?['locationId']",
                        "locationName": "@body('Filter_array')?[0]?['storageLocationName']",
                        "lotNumber": "@items('For_each')?['lotNumber']",
                        "sellByDate": "@items('For_each')?['sellByDate']"
                    },
                    "runAfter": {
                        "Filter_array": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    },
                    "type": "Compose"
                },
                "Filter_array": {
                    "inputs": {
                        "from": "@body('Select_ESO_Locations')",
                        "where": "@equals(string(item()['storageLocationId']), string(items('For_each')['locationId']))"
                    },
                    "runAfter": {},
                    "type": "Query"
                }
            },
            "foreach": "@body('Select_LSO_Locations')",
            "runAfter": {
                "Initialize_variable": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            },
            "type": "Foreach"
        }
```

**PS**
That being said, please consider following options too 
1) Use a liquid transform which will transform json to json. You will have more control on the transformation by writing a liquid transform. Note this requires an integration account and if you are using it in your enterprise, I would highly suggest this path
2) Use Azure functions to do the transform

Comment: liquid transform is a promising one to explore. But we do not have enterprise account right now. Regarding Azure functions do we have any advantage writing the above solution in function rather than just using a for each loop and filter as above with respect to cost/other things if any?

Comment: In my opinion, options 1 and 2 can be complimentary to each other. Provisioning an integration account in a production environment will consume some monetary resources which many people do not want to do in case the number of integrations used in their org are very less. 
In such cases I suggest option 2 where we write alternate mapping logic inside the Azure Functions
for. e.g instead of using Integration account to execute xslt transform, I create reusable azure function which executes the transform. Same can be implemented for json to json transformations using dot liquid library